# Can Windows 2000 drivers be used in XP?

Tags: windows-xp, usb, drivers, windows-2000

I have Windows 2000 USB drivers for my [PSION WaveFinder DAB radio receiver](http://www.geocities.com/epoc_32/wavefinder.html) but cannot find any for XP. Are Windows 2000 drivers suitable for XP? If so, how do I go about using them?

**EDIT:** Are there any differences/incompatibilities in 2000/XP driver models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows 2000 drivers for the device may or may not work under XP. Look for the directory that contains one or more `.inf` files. If there are several, you'll have to try the directories one at a time.

To give it a try, launch the Add Hardware applet from the Control Panel.

When you are prompted to choose the new device, scroll down to the bottom of the list and choose "Add a new hardware device".

Choose the "Install the hardware that I manually select from a list" option.

Choose "Show All Devices".

Press the "Have Disk" button, and point the textbox to the directory containing the `.inf` file(s).

Comment: Didn't think it would be that simple. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you are lucky - Try going in to computer manager, right clicking the device and doing install driver.

There is no one answer fits all - some thing work but most things do not (don't even think of trying graphics cards!).